# boost thread error <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm working on an optimisation project and have decided to try threads to increase the speed of my code. the format of the code is:

Main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    B *b = new B(argv[1]);
    b->foo();
    delete b;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

B.cpp:

```
#include B.hpp

B::B(const char *filename) { .... }

B::task1(){ /*nop*/ }

void B::foo() const { 
    boost::thread td(task1);
    td.join();
}
```

B.hpp:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class B{
    public:
    void task1();
    void foo();
}
```

however when I try to compile this code, I get an error at `boost::thread td(task1)`, saying:

`error: no matching function for call to 'boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'`

not entirely sure what the problem is and I've tried hacking away to no success. Any help is appreciated!

edit: new error

```
B.o: In function 'B::b() const':
B.cpp:(.text+0x7eb): undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
B.cpp:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::start_thread()'
B.cpp:(.text+0x9a2): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::join()'
B.cpp:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::~thread()'
B.cpp:(.text+0xb32): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::~thread()'
B.o: In function 'boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::cmf0<void, B>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<B const*> > > >::~thread_data()':
B.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi4cmf0Iv4BEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPKS6_EEEEEEED2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi4cmf0Iv4BEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPKS6_EEEEEEED5Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to 'boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B::task()` is a member function, so it takes an implicit first parameter of type `B*`. So you need to pass an instance to it in order to use it in a `boost::thread`.

```
void B::foo() const { 
  boost::thread td(&B::task1, this); // this is a const B*: requires task1() to be const.
  td.join();
}
```

But since `B::foo()` is a `const` method, you would have to make `B::task1()` a `const` method too:

```
class B {
  void task1() const:
}
```

Comment: In simplifying my code, I may have possibly oversimplified - my `B` class has a member variable which needs to be used within `task1()`. Creating a new B and binding with that would prevent me from using the objects variable, no?

Comment: @ElFik the example is just for illustration. You can pass `this` instead of `&b`. `this` is a `B*`.

Comment: @ElFik I changed the example to start the thread from within one of `B`'s methods.

Comment: thanks for your help here, but it appears to have a problem with my const declaration. I tried copying via `B b = this;` but just get the error:
`invalid conversion from 'const Mesh* const' to Mesh*`

Comment: @ElFik `foo()` is a const method, so it cannot modify `this`. So you cannot call any non-const methods from it. This means `this` is `const` inside that method. You would have to make `foo()` non-const, or `task1()` const.

Comment: ah of course, however I now get this rather incomprehensible error upon compilation:


`B.o: In function 'B::b() const':

B.cpp:(.text+0x7eb): undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'

B.cpp:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::start_thread()'

B.cpp:(.text+0x9a2): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::join()'

B.cpp:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::~thread()'

B.cpp:(.text+0xb32): undefined reference to 'boost::thread::~thread()'

B.o: In function `

Comment: @ElFik Maybe you need to link the `boost_thread` library. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934176/compiling-c-source-file-using-boost-thread). I use C++11 threads these days so I am afraid I have forgotten all the details.

Comment: oops, added the full message into the main Q

Comment: hmm, I'll accept your answer as it does correct the initial problem I was having, however I think there is an issue with my boost install so I'll look into that, thanks for the help